# Check if Rhythmbox is running via Python

Tags: python, dbus, rhythmbox

I am trying to extract information from Rhythmbox via `dbus`, but I only want to do so, if Rhythmbox is running. Is there a way to check if Rhythmbox is running via Python without starting it if it is not running?

Whenever I invoke the `dbus` code like this:

```
bus = dbus.Bus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.gnome.Rhythmbox", "/org/gnome/Rhythmbox/Shell")
iface = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.gnome.Rhythmbox.Shell)
```

and Rhythmbox is not running, it then starts it.

Can I check via `dbus` if Rhythmbox is running without actually starting it? Or is there any other way, other than parsing the list of currently running processes, to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to Rosh Oxymoron's answer, but arguably neater (albeit untested):

```
bus = dbus.SessionBus()
if bus.name_has_owner('org.gnome.Rhythmbox'):
    # ...
```

If you want to be notified when Rhythmbox starts or stops, you can use:

```
def rhythmbox_owner_changed(new_owner):
    if new_owner == '':
        print 'Rhythmbox is no longer running'
    else:
        print 'Rhythmbox is now running'

bus.watch_name_owner('org.gnome.Rhythmbox')
```

See the [documentation for dbus.bus.BusConnection](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/api/dbus.bus.BusConnection-class.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
dbus_main_object = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.DBus", "/")
dbus_names = dbus_main_object.ListNames(dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus')
if 'org.gnome.Rhythmbox' in dbus_names:
    do_whatever()
```